# MDX Show all months for a person if any of the months have a value of "Y" in a separate dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx

Have a funky issue i'm trying to resolve if you'd be so kind.

Measures: BillableHours

Dimensions:

Personnel (EmployeeId, EmployeeName)

Grouping(EmployeePeriodKey, ActiveFlag)

PeriodCalendarYear, CalendarQuarter, CalendarPeriod)

Grouping dimension has flags and calcs that are particular to a person in a period so the PK is the combo of EmployeeId and CalendarPeriod.

Data As Follows:

EmployeeId   CalendarPeriod   ActiveFlag   BillableHours

123              201501              Y                10

123              201502              Y                20

123              201503              N                30

123              201504              Y                40

People are filtering on "Active Flag" = "Y" and missing the "N" row in the results which is not what is desired.  Whatever filter I design needs to be flexible enough that at an employee level I need to know if an employee ever had a value of "Y" JUST the periods selected by the query.

Scenario 1: user selects employee 123 for periods 201501:201504 and filters hypothetical flag to "Y" - Billable Hours should be 100, not 70.

Scenario 2: user selects employee 123 for periods 201501:201503 and filters hypothetical flag to "Y" - Billable Hours should be 60, not 30.

Scenario 3: user selects employee 123 for period 201503 and filters hypothetical flag to "Y" - Billable Hours should be 0, not 30. since in this selected group of periods this person was not active for any period

i'm not interested in all siblings, just the ones at a person level.  And if person is not selected I need it to know to perform this check on a person level for the periods filtered for.  If they have the following

ActiveFlag: "Y"

Fiscal Year: 2016

Group             BillableHours

IT Consulting  1000

HR Consulting 1500

It would be understood that those total amounts represent the hours for every employee who was active for any part of FY2016 whether all 12 months or only 1.  If someone was active the year before, but weren't in 2016 they should not show up because I only want to interrogate the flags for the periods selected.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to see Y value when it's non empty? Otherwise N + Y value?

```
IIF(
    [Measures].[BillableHours] > 0,
    ([Grouping].[ActiveFlag].[All],[Measures].[BillableHours]),
    [Measures].[BillableHours]
)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what I needed to accomplish with the above is to have all values for a specific employee evaluated to see if any values for that employee were valid.  Through some Mosha posts and help on the MSDN forum I did work out an answer that I've posted.  I did +1 your answer, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

WhatI needed to accomplish with the above is to have all values for a specific employee evaluated to see if any values for that employee were valid. The key to doing that ended up being using EXISTING.  Additionally using NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR cut down on evaluation cycles because there was no need to evaluate the rows if they weren't active in a time period.  I've posted the MDX below.

```
CREATE HIDDEN UtilizedFTESummator;    
[Measures].[UtilizedFTESummator] = Iif([Measures].[Is Active For Utilization Value] > 0,[Measures].[Period FTE],NULL);    
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR([Measures].[UtilizedFTESummator]) = [Measures].[Is Active For Utilization Value];  

//only include this measure if the underlying employee has values in their underlying data for active in utilization
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[FTE Active Utilization]
AS
SUM
    (   
    EXISTING [Historical Personnel].[Employee Id].[Employee Id], 
    [Measures].[UtilizedFTESummator]
    ),VISIBLE=0;
```